# WebDav entries started to appear in IIS web logs last month in connection with Microsoft ClickOnce setup.exe files

Tags: iis, webdav, clickonce

Starting last month, log entries like this started to appear in our IIS web logs:

```
2020-09-08 17:31:07 192.168.1.99 OPTIONS /apps/foo/setup.exe - 80 - 192.168.1.77 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.19041 - 200 0 0 52
2020-09-08 17:31:07 192.168.1.99 PROPFIND /apps/foo/setup.exe - 80 - 192.168.1.77 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.19041 - 404 0 2 52
2020-09-08 17:31:07 192.168.1.99 PROPFIND /apps/foo - 80 - 192.168.1.77 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.19041 - 404 0 2 52
```

These `setup.exe` files are the executables created by Visual Studio when publishing a .NET desktop application to a LAN share for installation on the user's desktop via the web browser.

I am not sure what's going on there and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-webdav/using-the-webdav-redirector Simply means someone is using the WebDAV redirector.

Comment: But why is it happening specifically with the `setup.exe` files created by Visual Studio when publishing a .NET desktop application to a LAN share?  The applications themselves are not using WebDAV, and this suddenly started happening after a number of years of not happening. I am wondering if it has something to do with users switching from IE to Edge. I don't have any control over which browser users choose, and their Edge might not be configured to launch ClickOnce apps.